# Is it possible/ok to delete the header/image .deb files from a self-compiled Kernel in /usr/src?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, linux-kernel

As it is my first time compiling a kernel,I tried to compile a kernel version 2.6.35-rc6 but after 2-3 days of compilation the new kernel 2.6.35 came out. So, I'm wondering whether it's ok/possible to delete those header and image .deb files of 2.6.35-rc6 to discard them, as I no longer need them.

[I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid.]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove all those obsolete packages.

Comment: could you tell me how? I'm very new to kernel compiling. If you could guide me with some websites/links, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: @Joe If you need further assistance I'd suggest asking on askubuntu.com :)

Answer (score 0):

If they are no longer in use, I see no issue removing them, unless you wanted a fallback kernel in case the current one failed at some point. (If it's stable anyway)